# plotting multiple lines for SIR disease models

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I want help on plotting multiple lines for different parameters say \beta for different values `(\beta= 0.1, 0.2, 0.4 etc)`, the graph will be for `dy_2/dt`, meaning that `plot(T, y_2( :,2)` only, or `plot(T,y_2(:,3))` then the plot to be Time vs Infected for different values of \beta. I have tried the following code:

```matlab
function EulerSIRTenga()
  clear all; clc;
  rho = 0.7; Lambda = 0.4; beta = 0.9;theta1 = 0.1; 
  theta2 = 0.2;theta3 = 0.1;alpha = 0.33;omega = 0.4;psi = 0.3;
  R0 = rho * beta/(theta1+ Lambda)

  options =odeset('RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',[1e-4 1e-4 1e-4 1e-4 1e-4]);
  [T,Y] = ode45(@SIRmodel,[0 365],[0.9,0.7,0.5,0.15,0.35],options);

  plot(T, Y(:,1),'g',T,Y(:,2),'r',T,Y(:,3),'k',T,Y(:,4),'b',T,Y(:,5),'m', 'Linewidth',2);
  xlabel('Time','FontSize',14);
  ylabel('Proportion of population','FontSize',14)
  legend('Susceptibles','Infected', 'AIDS on ART','Detectable VL','Undetectable VL')
  title('Deterministic solution for the proportion of population vs time','FontSize',14);
  grid on
  box on


  function dy=SIRmodel(t,y)
    dy=zeros(5,1);
    dy(1)= rho*Lambda - (beta*y(2)+Lambda-alpha*(y(3)+y(4)+y(5)))*y(1);
    dy(2)=(1-rho)*Lambda+(beta*y(1)-theta1-Lambda+alpha*(y(3)+y(4)+y(5)))*y(2);
    dy(3)= theta1*y(2)+ theta2*y(4)+theta3*y(5)-(alpha+omega+Lambda-alpha*(y(3)+y(4)+y(5)))*y(3);
    dy(4)= psi*omega*y(3)-(alpha+theta2+Lambda-alpha*(y(3)+y(4)+y(5)))*y(4);
    dy(5)=(1-psi)*omega*y(3)-(alpha-theta3+Lambda-alpha*(y(3)+y(4)+y(5)))*y(5);
  end
end
```

I want the graph to look like the Figure below:

[image: I need values of \beta to vary at different rates]

I need to vary the values of \beta to vary at different rates.

This is the figure my codes is producing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWTEH.png)

Comment: Could you please add the code you tried until now so that we can better understand what is your problem?

Comment: I would store the values for all lines in a matrix and the plotting them one by one in a loop. Plotting multiple lines on the graph can be achieved specifying setting the hold property of the figure to "on". You do that with the command `hold on`

Comment: @Thombou i have attached codes please

Comment: Could you also attach the figure produced by this code please?

Comment: This would give a completely overloaded plot. You have the graphs of 5 different functions, and you want to add 5 variants of this function set to the plot. It would make sense to have 5 plots, one for each function and its variants.

Comment: @Thombou I have attached the figure produced by the code

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes that is what i wanted to plot help me get a loop of one function among them then to check the effect of parameter \beta for different values.

Comment: Then do what @Thombou proposes, build the table of solution variants, and then loop over the functions to plot, with an inner loop over the variants from the table.